# create print button with enable and disable based on cell value excel

Tags: excel, vba, printing, controls, enable-if

Is there a way to create a print button that will start disabled and when my cell value in A1 =1 it will become enbaled to print a woksheet and when it is done it will disable itself again? It is an ActiveX button.

Comment: Ok, A1 responds to conditions in my workshet that I have already setup. If all my conditions are met then A1 has a vlue of 1 if not it equals 0. the button would then enable me to print a specific sheet in my workbook.

Answer (score 3):

Put this into the worksheet's private code sheet (right-click worksheet name tab, View Code) and edit if necessary to refer to the correct ActiveX button.

```
Option Explicit


Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1")) Is Nothing Then
        CommandButton1.Enabled = CBool(Range("A1") = 1)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Range("a1").ClearContents

    'do all the printing code here
    MsgBox "printing ..."


End Sub
```